# Restrict custom post type from appearing with ?post_types=

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, security

When appending the querystring post_types = "name of your post type", it displays all the posts. I am using a plugin that has its own custom post type which is restricted (only users that have purchased a membership can view it).. but today while messing around with searching, i discovered that post_types querystring. Is there a way to prevent this private custom type from showing up? are there other similar "magic" querystring in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has quite a few related arguments, of which `publicly_queryable` controls precisely what you are describing.

However note that it will *completely* kill the CPT on front end — individual posts, archives, even post previews.

If you want to do this conditionally you'll have to manage this with code from scratch, which might get very involved to do comprehensively.

Comment: Is ?post_types=mycpt available by default on wp? I turned out that it's the plugin "Search & Filter" that enables this? I am not sure

Comment: @yeahman default CPT registration sets `public` (which includes this, unless specified otherwise) to `false`. If plugin provides CPT that completely depends on arguments plugin registers it with.

Comment: so the query_var ?post_types exists by default on wp? when i disable the "Search and filter" plugin, it displays the homepage when i add the ?post_types querystring

Comment: @yeahman hm, actually native query var is `post_type` (singular). This is probably indeed implemented by plugin and completely up to it.

Comment: yup but there's still the issue with ?post_type= lol... are there any other query like this that may reveal "private" posts? (taxonomy maybe?)

Comment: @yeahman this is not a "reveal", if post is registered as public it is considered public. If it's not then it won't show up in queries.

Comment: any way to restrict access at query level by capability of the logged in user?